# php array - upper case or lower case

Tags: php, arrays, coding-style

Does it matter whether an uppercase or lower case `a` is used for php arrays?

For example: `array()` vs. `Array()`

Comment: I had that question once. Took about a minute to test.

Comment: @ManosDilaverakis For sure, it is about standards and not testing. New PHP versions bring changes and thus such a question is absolutely justified. The PHP docs state [array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) *not* Array(). @David: If you are not sure, simply use `$newarray = []`;

Answer (score 11):

I believe the OP is referring to this:

```
<?php
$arr = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);
var_dump($arr);
// returns array(2) { ["foo"]=>  string(3) "bar" [12]=>  bool(true) }

$arr = Array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);
var_dump($arr);
// also returns array(2) { ["foo"]=>  string(3) "bar" [12]=>  bool(true) }
?>
```

So the answer is no, there is no difference

Answer (score 3):

If you mean:

```
$array = Array(1,2,3);
```

vs

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
```

vs

```
$array = aRRaY(1,2,3);
```

there is no functional difference.  It is only a question of style.  Like PHP functions, the [array language construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean array names/variables, then yes it does, PHP variables are [case-sensitive](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/variables.php). If however, you are asking about standards, have a look at:

[PHP Coding Standard about Naming Conventions](http://www.dagbladet.no/development/phpcodingstandard/#names)

Comment: Also, array keys are case sensitive if you use strings not numbers. They are normal strings and compared as strings.

Comment: I dont think the OP is asking about variables - i think he is referring to the use of the word "Array" or "array"

Comment: @seengee: yeah that might be it

Answer (score 0):

David - yes it does. they are treated as different variables $varPerson and $varperson.

However, the main thing really is more that you should be following some kind of coding guideline doc that mandates case and scope of all variables. this is probably a much more important driver of variable naming/case than the simple question implies.

jim